# Socket.io code is not updating on DOM when I disconnect or when I have multiple tabs of the same user. But, when I connect, it works fine. Why?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, dom, socket.io

I will try to be as detailed as possible. I am trying to make an app where people can individually message each other and this code is to show the list of online users. So, my plan is I would append to the li when users connect(so far, that is working correctly).
However, I am having issues when there are multiple tabs of the same user or when a user disconnects,. The DOM just isn't updating properly.

What is wrong with this code? Are there any better approaches and if so, how should I manipulate the DOM? The list for active users is to remove when a user becomes inactive and add to it when a user is active. Thanks in advance

Server side code:

```
let users={};
let send=[];
io.on("connection", async (socket)=>{
    console.log("new WS connection");
    socket.on("login", async function(user_id){
        socket.handshake.session.user_id = user_id;
        socket.handshake.session.save();
        
    });

    socket.on("logout", function(user_id){
        if(socket.handshake.session.user_id){
            delete socket.handshake.session.user_id;
            socket.handshake.session.save();
        }
    });

    let currentSession=socket.handshake.session.user_id;
    if(typeof currentSession !== "undefined" && typeof socket.id !== "undefined"){
        if(users[currentSession]){
            users[currentSession].push(socket.id);
        }
        else{
            users[currentSession]=new Array();
            users[currentSession].push(socket.id);
        }
    }
     
    console.log("users dict before");
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(users)) {
        console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
      }

    let arr = Array.from(io.sockets.sockets.keys()); //connected sockets

    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(users)) {
        for(let v of value){
            if(arr.includes(v)){
                io.emit("listOfUsers", await utils.getUserInfo(key));
            }
        }
    }
    send=[];
    socket.on("disconnect", async ()=>{
        let userLeft=await utils.getUserInfo(socket.handshake.session.user_id);
        io.emit("msg", utils.formatMessage("Bot", `${userLeft} has left the chat`));
        console.log("User disconnected socket id", socket.id);

        arr = Array.from(io.sockets.sockets.keys());
        console.log("connected sockets", arr);

        let save=[];
        console.log("final");
        for(let [key, value] of Object.entries(users)){
            for(let i=0; i<value.length; i++){
                for(let a of arr){
                    if(a === value[i]){
                        if(!save.includes(key)) save.push(key);

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        io.emit("disconnectList", await utils.getUserInfo(save));
        console.log("save", save);

    })

})
```

Client side Code:

```
let chatForm=document.querySelector("#chat-form");
let fullMessageBox=document.querySelector(".full-message-box");
let ul=document.querySelector(".the-ul");
let li=document.querySelectorAll(".active-people-li");
let socket=io();

socket.on("msg", message=>{
    console.log(message,"m");
    outputMessage(message);  //Outputs message to DOM

    fullMessageBox.scrollTop=fullMessageBox.scrollHeight;

});

socket.on("user_id", msg=>{
    console.log("front end session ", msg);
    socket.emit("user_connected", msg);
});

let record=[];
socket.on("listOfUsers", msg=>{
    if(!record.includes(msg.id)){
        record.push(msg.id);
        outputActiveUsers(msg);
    }
    // console.log(msg);
})

let record2=[];
socket.on("disconnectList", msg=>{
    console.log("this");
    for(let m of msg){
        outputActiveUsers(m);
    }
})

chatForm.addEventListener("submit", (event)=>{
    event.preventDefault();

    let msgInput=document.querySelector("#msg-input").value;
    socket.emit("chatMsg", msgInput);
    document.querySelector("#msg-input").value="";
    document.querySelector("#msg-input").focus();
    
})

async function outputMessage(msg){
    let div=document.createElement("div");
    div.classList.add("msg-wrapper");
     div.innerHTML=`<div class="msg-wrapper">
                        <div class="msg">
                            <p>${msg.text}</p>
                        </div>
                        <span id="you-time" class="time">${msg.time}</span>
                    </div>`;
    document.querySelector(".msg-wrapper").appendChild(div);

}

function outputActiveUsers(msg){
    let li=document.createElement("li");
    li.classList.add("active-people-li");
    li.innerHTML= `<div class="active-sidebar">
                        <div class="div-of-img">
                            <img src="../files/profile.png" alt="" class="active-profile-img">
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <a href=""><h4>${msg.name}</h4></a>
                            <h5>Hi. Is this you, bro?</h5>
                        </div>
                    </div>`;
    document.querySelector(".the-ul").appendChild(li);
}
```

The HTML file linked to the client side code:

```
<div class="active-chat-div">
                    <div class="active-chat-text">
                        <h3>Active Chats</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="active-people">
                        <ul class="the-ul">
                            <!-- <li class="active-people-li">

                                <div class="active-sidebar">
                                    <div class="div-of-img">
                                        <img src="../files/profile.png" alt="" class="active-profile-img">
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <a href=""><h4>Nafi</h4></a>
                                        <h5>Hi. Is this you, bro?</h5>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                        
                            </li> -->
                                
                            <!-- <li class="active-people-li">
                                <div class="active-sidebar">
                                    <div>
                                        <img src="../files/profile.png" alt="" class="active-profile-img">
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <a href=""><h4>Nafi</h4></a>
                                        <h5>Hi. Is this you, bro?</h5>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                        
                            </li> -->
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
```